# Netbeans keeps crashing on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: netbeans

I am trying to run Netbeans. But it keeps getting crashed after initializing.
Here, what I am getting on my terminal
Thanks.

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory (file:/usr/share/netbeans/platform18/lib/boot.jar) to field java.net.URL.handler
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.ProxyURLStreamHandlerFactory
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

Comment: You appear to be impacted by [this bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894715) but it's hard to be certain without more information.

Comment: What's your Java version and Netbeans version? How did you installed Netbeans?